# File based cache or many mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, performance, caching

Lets assume you're developing a multiplayer game where the data is stored in a MySQL-database. For example the names and description texts of items, attributes, buffs, npcs, quests etc.

That data:

- won't change often
- is frequently requested
- is required on server-side
- and cannot be cached locally (JSON, Javascript)

To solve this problem, i wrote a **file-based caching system** that creates .php-files on the server and copies the **entire mysql-tables** as pre-defined php variables into them.

Like this:

```
$item_names = Array(0 => "name", 1 => "name");
$item_descriptions = Array(0 => "text", 1 => "text");
```

That file contains a loot of data, will end up having a size of around 500 KB and is then loaded on every user request.

Is that a good attempt to avoid unnecessary queries; Considering that **query-caching is being deprecated in MySQL 8.0**? Or is it better to just get the data needed using individual queries, even if ending up with hundreds of them per request?

Comment: Just make the tables InnoDB, and increase the [InnoDB buffer pool size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html) to approx. 70% of your server RAM. You will have almost same effect as caching, because the frequently used pages will be in the RAM (buffer pool)

Comment: Use InnoDB.  Period.  Full-stop.  Move on to some other problem.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use some kind of PSR-6 compilant cache system (it could be filesystem also) and later when your requests grow you can easily swap out to a more performant cache, like a PSR-6 Redis cache.

Example for [PSR-6 compatible file system cache](https://github.com/override2k/psr-cache).

More info about [PSR-6 Caching Interface](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-6/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making your own caching mechanism, you can use `Redis` as it will handle all your caching requirements.

It will be easy to implement.

Follow the links to get to know more about Redis

[REDIS](https://redislabs.com/)

[REDIS IN PHP](https://redislabs.com/lp/php-redis/)

[REDIS PHP TUTORIALS](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/redis_php.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience...

You should only optimize for performance when you can prove you have a problem, and when you know where that problem is.

That means in practice that you should write load tests to exercise your application under "reasonable worst-case scenario" loads, and instrument your application so you can see what its performance characteristics are.

Doing any kind of optimization without a load test framework means you're coding on instinct; you may be making things worse without knowing it.

Your solution - caching entire tables in arrays - means every PHP process is loading that data into memory, which may or may not become a performance hit in its own right (do you *know* which request will need which data?). It also looks like you'll be doing a lot of relational logic in PHP (in your example, gluing the item_name to the item_description). This is something MySQL is really good at; your PHP code could easily be slower than MySQL at joins.

Then you have the problem of cache invalidation - how and when do you refresh the cached data? How does your application behave when the data is being refreshed? I've seen web sites slow to a crawl when cached data was being refreshed.

In short - it's a complicated decision, there are no obvious right/wrong answers. My first recommendation is "build a test framework so you can approach performance based on evidence", my second is "don't roll your own - consider using an ORM with built-in cache support", my third is "consider using something like Redis or memcached to store your cache information".

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions, depends on your requirements. Possible solution could be:

- File base JSON format caching. Data retrieve from database will be save to a file for next time use before the program process.
- Memory base cache, such as Memcached, APC, Redis, etc. Similar the upon solution, better performance but more integrated code required.
- Memory base database, such as NoSQL, MongoDB, etc. It is a memory base database.
- Multiple database servers, one master write database with multiple salve for read databases, there are a synchronisation between servers.

Quick and minimise the code changes, I suggest using option B.